# Is there a function like remoteRun where a string can be passed as a function and ConstantSP as its arguments, but can be executed locally?

Tags: dolphindb

Is there a function like `remoteRun` where a string can be passed as a function and ConstantSP as its arguments, but can be executed locally? For example, I want to execute `remoteRun(conn, "add{1}", 2)`  on my local server, but `xdb()` doesn't allow me to connect to my own server.

Answer (score 0):

If your function doesn't have partial applications, use `funcByName` to parse the string:

```
call(funcByName("add"),1,2)
```

If your function contains partial application, you can use `parseExpr`:

```
call(parseExpr("add{1}").eval(), 2)
```

where `parseExpr("add{1}").eval()` returns a function.